# How to download and install ROS Fuerte in 2019?

Tags: ros, binaries, ros-fuerte, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to implement someone else's project code to recreate their results. They've left build instructions, and running instructions, which is great. The only issue is, the original project was implemented on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin with ROS Fuerte, and is too sprawling for me to have a reasonable chance of successfully migrating it to a newer Ubuntu/ROS.

I was able to get a virtual machine running with Ubuntu 12.04 on it. When it came to installing ROS Fuerte, I followed the instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu), but when I try to install the pre-built binaries with apt-get (Step 1.4), I get the error

> E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-desktop-full

I'm assuming that because Fuerte has long since passed its EOL date, the binaries have been taken off the server. I also tried to install it from [source](http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source), but ran into an error in step 1.2.2:

> ERROR in config: Unable to download URL [http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no]: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Have these files been moved somewhere? What is the best way to go about installing ROS Fuerte in 2019?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340464/how-to-download-and-install-ros-fuerte-in-2019?/) by [saltus](https://answers.ros.org/users/37231/saltus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2019-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-12-20**:
Does this post help in working around the disappearance of the `gen_rosinstall.py` script from packages.ros.org when you try to build from source.? https://answers.ros.org/question/82421/fuerte-source-install-gen_rosinstallpy-not-found/

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-12-20**:
The answer from @gvdhoorn is likely much more useful. I focused in on why you were having the source build error, but he's right, avoiding building from source is definitely preferable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm assuming that because Fuerte has long since passed its EOL date,

true.

> the binaries have been taken off the server.

The *main repositories* have been cleaned up and don't serve the Fuerte binaries any more.

However, the [SnapshotRepository](http://wiki.ros.org/SnapshotRepository) still has everything available.

Follow the instructions there, don't be confused by the fact that `fuerte` is not listed in the table on that page, but do realise there is only a `final` snapshot available, as explained in the [Snapshots of End-Of-Life ROS distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/SnapshotRepository#Snapshots_of_End-Of-Life_ROS_distributions) section.

That should allow you to install the <del>latest</del> *last* builds of all Fuerte packages.

> I also tried to install it from source,

Please don't do this, unless absolutely necessary.

> I was able to get a virtual machine running with Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

As an alternative you could consider using the [Docker images for legacy ROS versions](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-docker-images-for-legacy-ros-releases/2843). That could also let you avoid the VM, which is always a good thing imho.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saltus](https://answers.ros.org/users/37231/saltus/) on 2019-12-20**:
Thanks for the tip! The SnapshotRepository is exactly what I'm looking for.

> That could also let you avoid the VM, which is always a good thing imho.

I agree, I originally created a partition to install 12.04 on, but getting the hardware drivers to work with my current setup was a nightmare. So I figured the VM was a necessary evil. I'll definitely take a look at those Docker images and see if they're a better fit for what I'm trying to do.